How to position camera to center fit a 3d model inside a SK3DNode in SceneKit
I want to be able to center fit a 3D model inside a SK3DNode. I have the following code:
public extension SK3DNode {
  static func forModel(_ model: SCNNode, size: CGSize) -> SK3DNode {
    let scene = SCNScene()
    let node3D = SK3DNode()
    node3D.scnScene = scene
    node3D.viewportSize = size
    
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(model)

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    node3D.pointOfView = cameraNode
    
    cameraNode.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: model)]
    // TODO: adjust position to center fit the model
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 4)
    
    return node3D
  }
}

I have done the following:
    let planeX = model.boundingSize.x
    let planeY = model.boundingSize.y
    let planeLength = max(planeX, planeY)
    let angleInRadian = NumberUtil.degreeToRadian(degree: camera.fieldOfView)
    let distance = planeLength / 2 / tan(angleInRadian/2)

I got the above calculation based on the picture in this answer: Camera position based on model size?
This seems to be close to what I want, but it doesn't consider the size and aspect ratio of the viewport in the calculation, so I don't think it's correct. Is there a better way to compute this?
EDIT:
Here you can download a sample project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W_v0jMR1w9SkP-__SlKcPfiRF9cpTyEb/view?usp=sharing
When you run it, you will see 4 SK3DNodes (see the 4 blue areas in the screenshot below), and they are (from top to bottom):

A tall viewport with a wide 3d model inside
A tall viewport with a tall 3d model inside
A wide viewport with a tall 3d model inside
A wide viewport with a wide 3d model inside

I want to control the camera so that all 3D models will appear to "center fit" the viewport.


Maybe I understand some things wrong, but why don't you adjust all your models scale in a way they are more or less of the same size? (i.Ex. using the Bounding Box calculation discussed in your other question). Why should you adjust the camera distance? Or could you deeper clarify your intention here?

But even if i want to scale to the same size, i still need to compute what's the camera distance so that it fits the SK3DNode, isn't it? So forget about models being different sizes, assume they are more or less the same size (to be accurate, the same size in the longest dimension, since they may have different aspect ratio in 3 dimensions, e.g. one may be taller while the others may be wider or longer), the same question still holds

Can you share a minimum reproducible example (Full code or project to download from some cloud service, including some models)

@ZAY I have attached the sample project above. Thank you!

I can see the Blue Stuff and the White content, the I run the App... But I do not understand, what you want to have centered and where. I cannot see a Model or similar. Do you have some "better" example code? Also here, I consider you to think about using the real SceneKit in dedicated Views, where you need them...

The model is the white box, and the viewport is the blue view. I want the white box to center fit the viewport, meaning that white box should occupy as much space as possible without going outside of the viewport.

I came up with the solution: I need to set the projectionDirection based on the model's aspect ratio and the viewport's aspect ratio.
For example, this code below sets the models (white boxes) to center fit the viewports (blue windows) with a padding of 20%.
    let modelSize = model.boundingSize
    let modelAspectRatio = modelSize.x / modelSize.y
    let viewportAspectRatio = Float(viewportSize.width / viewportSize.height)
    let h: Float
    
    let paddingRatio: Float = 0.8
    let angleInRadian = Float(camera.fieldOfView * .pi / 180)

    if modelAspectRatio > viewportAspectRatio {
      // model is wider, use horizontal axis for FOV computation
      camera.projectionDirection = .horizontal
      h = (modelSize.x / paddingRatio) / 2 / tanf(angleInRadian/2)
    } else {
      camera.projectionDirection = .vertical
      h = (modelSize.y / paddingRatio) / 2 / tanf(angleInRadian/2)
    }
    
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: h + modelSize.z/2)

And as you can see from the result, all the white boxes are scaled to center fit the blue viewport, with a padding of 20%.


You need to consider the depth of the 3d model while calculating the distance from the camera to the model or it would be calculated from the model center (or origin point) to the camera.
This adjustment would take care of everything
P.S. You don't need also to be at 90% of the size. you would be perfectly having the model in the camera viewport.
    // get the boundingBox aka maximun size of X Y Z of the model (no need for /0.9)
    let planeX = model.boundingBox.max.x
    let planeY = model.boundingBox.max.y
    
    // you need planZ to get the depth of the 3d model for accurate
    // distance calculation
    let planeZ = model.boundingBox.max.z
    
    let planeLength = max(planeX, planeY)
    
    // to convert to radian you can multiply the angle to (.pi/180)
    let angleInRadian: Float = Float(cameraNode.camera!.fieldOfView * (.pi/180))

    
    // this is the distance from the center of the 3d model to the camera
    let distance = planeLength / 2 / tan(angleInRadian/2)
    
    // you have to add half the depth of the 3d model to it
    let actualDistance = distance + (planeZ/2)
    
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: actualDistance)

Update:
The full code would be like that:
public extension SK3DNode {
    static func forModel(_ model: SCNNode, viewportSize: CGSize) -> SK3DNode {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        scene.background.contents = UIImage.color(size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1), color: .blue)
        let node3D = SK3DNode()
        node3D.scnScene = scene
        node3D.viewportSize = viewportSize
        
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(model)
        
        let camera = SCNCamera()
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        node3D.pointOfView = cameraNode
        
        cameraNode.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: model)]
        // TODO: adjust camera position so that the viewport fits the model
        
        // get the boundingBox aka maximun size of X Y Z of the model (no need for /0.9)
        let planeX = model.boundingBox.max.x
        let planeY = model.boundingBox.max.y
        
        // you need planZ to get the depth of the 3d model for accurate
        // distance calculation
        let planeZ = model.boundingBox.max.z
        
        let planeLength = max(planeX, planeY)
        
        // to convert to radian you can multiply the angle to (.pi/180)
        let angleInRadian: Float = Float(cameraNode.camera!.fieldOfView * (.pi/180))
        
        // this is the distance from the center of the 3d model to the camera
        let distance = planeLength / 2 / tan(angleInRadian/2)
        
        // you have to add half the depth of the 3d model to it
        let actualDistance = distance + (planeZ/2)
        
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: actualDistance)
        
        return node3D
    }
    
}

And Here is the image from the device.


This doesn't consider the size of the viewport (the size of the SK3DNode)? Imagine we have 2 cases: a very tall viewport size, vs another very wide viewport size? We have to do something different right?

I have updated my question with a sample project. Thank you!

oh I understand it wrong that you want to do this for every 3d model separately, but now that you clarify it for me I knew that it needs another calculations to show all 4 models in the same size in one screen. I think it may also include calculations for the rotation of the camera not only the position.

Oh I didn't think about rotation. You are right. For my case, my camera always look into the center of the model, which should make the problem easier. I suspect that with rotation it would be too hard to solve

I cannot say it is an easy task to make this calculations for the distance and rotation but it is possible for old geometry low level coders using radian sin, cos to reposition and rotate to make sure the camera facing a certain point at all the time, this is now done for modern programmers using the function LookAt() which makes coding easy but unfortunately it works only for a single model not the whole view which can include several models. I'm so excited of the results that I would follow your progress for some times in this post I guess. This thumb up from me

Yes only 1 single model in my case, which is likely easier as you said.

I have downloaded your code and update it with my codes and I have updated my answer, Please check the image, is this what you want?

@OMGPOP, did it work for you , talking about my last update on my answer?

Why are the white boxes gone? the are supposed to center fit the viewport.

To clarify, the purpose of this exercise is to "center fit" a 3d model (which are the white boxes) within a viewport (which are the blue windows)

Ok let me review your codes first to see the white boxes
